# Send data to another view using Prebuilt UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, iphone, view, sdk, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a Tab Bar Application using Xcode that as two views.

The secound view is a UITableViewController.

What I am struggling to do is send data to this view, when the second tab is pressed. I have delegated the Tab Bar to my AppDelegate class and implemented this function:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    statisticsViewController* assignmentListcont = [statisticsViewController alloc];

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];

    assignmentListcont.managedObjectContext = context;

    [assignmentListcont release];

}
```

The second view is displaying fine but the data hasn't been passed. I imagine its because I haven't programmed the second views transition but I'm unsure of how to do this if I already have a .xib file doing it for me? Is there some way to just pass the data without problems or even retrieve the data once inside the view?

Answer (score 0):

You could use notifications.

In the view that you want to receive the data, put this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(yourSelector:) 
                                      name:@"addedData" 
                                      object:nil];
```

Then implement the method that receives that data:

```
- (void)yourSelector:(NSNotification *)notification {
         Foo *foo;
     foo = [notification object];
    //do something else
}
```

Now in the class where the data is originated from, you post a notification that new data was created.  Also, you pass along the data that you want to have the other method receive.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addedData" 
                                      object:foo];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the end I used the global delegate method from http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html.

Comment: No problem!  Wish you the best success. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this to send a value from one view controller to another, hope it helps

```
UITabBarViewController *var = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"name"]; //I select the UITabBarController
otherViewController *var2 = [var.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; //I Select the first ViewController from that UITabBarController
var2.variable = @"value";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:var animated:YES];
```